# How To Get Index Of Array Using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array that isn't normal. Which can be accessed using index.

For example: I have an array and if I want to access it, I only need to use `myArray[0]` or `myArray.name`.

But, my array below is different:

[image: get Index Of Array Using JavaScript]

```
[]
  name: Array(4)
        0 : {_id: "5b6bad0d7e9f754ff8aebd66", username: "tisufa", password: "12345"}
        1 : {_id: "5b6bad367e9f754ff8aebd67", username: "titus", password: "88888"}
        2 : {_id: "5b6c0f2c5978404d7431d589", username: "titus", password: "8888"}
        3 : {_id: "5b7103cdabcb573894cc1875", username: "nn", password: "22222"}
```

I tried to access `myArray['name']` or `myArray.name`, but I can't do it.

I have tried to use:

```
for(let key in myArray){
     console.log(key);
}
```

but, I also can't access the `key` of the array. I got the information `undefined`

I beg for your help.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like a malformed array. Arrays shouldn't have `name` properties. Better to fix the code that generates it, so that you can then use standard array methods and index notation.

Answer (score 1):

`myArray.name[0]`

For some reason, you created an array and then created another array inside that array. I was able to reproduce what you did with this code:

```
let myArray = []
myArray['name'] = []
```

Find where you're doing this and fix it, or make your outer array an object:

```
let myArray = {} // This is an object
myArray['name'] = []
```

In both cases, you can access and loop through your array like so:

```
console.log(myArray.name) // print entire array
for(let i in myArray.name)
     console.log(myArray.name[i]) // print each element in array
```

Comment: Thank you sir, for your response. I have tried it, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr_obj = [
    {_id: "5b6bad0d7e9f754ff8aebd66", username: "tisufa", password: "12345"},
    {_id: "5b6bad367e9f754ff8aebd67", username: "titus", password: "88888"},
    {_id: "5b6c0f2c5978404d7431d589", username: "titus", password: "8888"},
    {_id: "5b7103cdabcb573894cc1875", username: "nn", password: "22222"},
];

for(let [index,data] of arr_obj.entries()){
    console.log("index:",index,"data:",data);
}
```

ES6 for of and entries

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tZ5v.png)

Comment: Thank you sir, for your response. I have tried it, but it still doesn't work. Because myArray it's not look like that.